# Cannot understand rails deprecation warning for secret_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

After upgrading from `rails 5.1` to `rails 5.2.3` I am getting this deprecation warning:

```
secrets.secret_token` is deprecated in favor of `secret_key_base` and will be removed in Rails 6.0. (called from <main> at /config/initializers/stripe.rb:3
```

If I look at the stripe initializer, I have:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  publishable_key: Rails.application.secrets.stripe_publishable_key,
  secret_key:      Rails.application.secrets.stripe_secret_key
}
```

so there is no mention of `secret.token`. If I look at `config.secrets.yml` I have

```
test:
  secret_key_base: some-key
  stripe_secret_key: another_key
  stripe_publishable_key: yet_another_key
```

So why am I getting the deprecation warning?

Comment: I guess you're saying it's happening only in test environment. What's your key looks like in other environment in *config/secrets.yml*

Comment: Are you using stripe-ruby (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby)? The error does not seems to stripe related. Just want to make sure/

Comment: I am using stripe-ruby. The keys have the same format in production and development. I do not think it is a stripe problem.

Comment: I do not get the message if I start the rails server or console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 5.2 has replaced secrets with credentials to store encrypted credentials or API keys in the repository. You can read more about the changing from secrets to credentials in the following article.

https://medium.com/@wintermeyer/goodbye-secrets-welcome-credentials-f4709d9f4698

Even though Rails 5.2 has replaced secrets with credentials, you can still use secrets if you wish to. However as the warning message states, secrets will be removed from Rails 6 and you have to embrace in using credentials for storing API keys and secret_keys.